# mongodump: "there are no users authenticated" but authentication is disabled

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I have MongoDB 4.2 on localhost with authentication disabled. I have never even created any users. But When I try to use mongodump like this: `mongodump --uri mongodb://localhost:27017 --out dump` I get `there are no users authenticated`.

I am on Windows and all I did was run `mongod.exe` with no options. I never enabled authentication, and I never created any users.

I am able to connect perfectly fine with no credentials using the `mongo` shell, and Compass. So why is mongodump giving me a problem?

Comment: does the problem go away if you replace `localhost` with 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Figured it out on my own and forgot I posted with question. Yes that was what fixed it.